# What is this component called (Plastic housing with screws for connecting wires)?

Tags: identification

This is part of a PIR sensor circuit. The component in question is the black array where wires can be fastened. I tried searching the web, but for lack of any tangible keywords, I came up empty handed.

[image]

Comment: Wire to board terminal blocks, and by the looks of it regular screw tightening? Just make sure you find the appropriate pitch and everything

Comment: If you googled "Plastic housing with screws for connecting wires" the third hit would include the phrase "Terminal Blocks" in the title. I'm voting to close this down as lack of research.

Comment: @Andyaka I must admit, that is an awfully specific search term. I tried "multiple pin contact", "multiple pin circuit", "multiple wire component" and combinations thereof. I hindsight, after reading the answer, your suggestion makes much more sense and seems trivial, but so do many things once you learn them.

Comment: Well, mister forgetful, they are the words in your title!

Comment: @Andyaka - Don't forget: Questions can be edited by other users. In OP's defense, that title was edited by me. In OP's offense, I'm not a fan of vague titles like "What is this?" or "How can I fix my circuit?".

Comment: There's an inherent problem with identification questions: since the core of the question is a picture, they are bound to be asked over and over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a screw terminal block.
As you can see in your provided image: Wires go inside. Loosen the screws, insert wires, tighten screws, done. No soldering or crimping required.

Comment: It also gets in various dimensions, but most common known are 2 or 3 in a row, which could be extended as one to the side of the other. And most common color is green or blue.

Comment: I also see these referred to as 'PCB mount elevator clamps'.

Comment: Someone care to explain the downvote? Seems odd to me.

Comment: Yes, it was me but in hindsight my bitchiness was unwarranted. If you make a trivial edit to your post I can remove the downvote.